# how to check checkbox in run time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add checked option to checkbox if it has an id or value of 2 at runtime using javascript. I tried with following code, but I am unable to check the checkbox. Any ideas?

```
<div>
        <h4>Filter by Area</h4>             
            <ul id="arealist">
    <li><input type ="checkbox"  id="1" value="1" /> All</li>
    <li><input type ="checkbox"   id="2" value="2" /> some</li>
    <li><input type ="checkbox"   id="3" value="3" /> heavy</li>
    <li><input type ="checkbox"   id="4" value="4" /> more</li>
    <li><input type ="checkbox"   id="5" value="5" /> none</li>

                                            </ul>   </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  
var areaname=2; //this value i am getting at run time.
$("#areaname").prop("checked",true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: try `$("#areaname").attr('checked', 'checked');`

Comment: Hi @arunes, Its not working. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Sorry, i missed that variable, try `$("#" + areaname).attr('checked', 'checked');` as @Xeon06 said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ID attribute cannot be just an integer, it must begin with a letter. If you name them something like area1, area2, area3 etc... and update your code it should work fine. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8YFF/) with an updated version working fine.

Comment: Hi srinu thanks for the accept :) Please go ahead and give @Xeon06 a vote up as well for posting an equally useful answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to concatenate your string.

```
$("#" + areaname).prop("checked", true);
```

**[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/rv4HD/)**

Also, [your ID names are invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/104999). Think of them as variables. Use names that don't start with numbers, don't have spaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#" + areaname).attr("checked", true);
```

Instead of

```
$("#areaname").prop("checked",true);
```

Comment: Why did you switch `prop` to `attr`?

Comment: No reason, I always use attr - I guess it's just a preference.

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/104999